# How do I import from a great-great-grandparent directory in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I feel a little embarrassed for not knowing this already but it's something I've always struggled with. I have a directory like this:

```
marketing-reports/
     utils.py
     Reporting/
          Adhoc/
               for_sales/
                    salesperson1/
                         current.py
```

I want to import `utils.py` from `current.py` but every suggestion I have seen so far does not work.

I have seen two main suggestions. The first involves using sys.path. I have tried that as below:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:\\marketing-reports\\Reporting')
from Reporting import utils
```

... result is:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError 
No module named 'Reporting'
```

I have also tried another suggestion I got from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-parent-directory/) like

```
import path
import sys

# directory reach
directory = path.path(__file__).abspath()

# setting path
sys.path.append(directory.parent.parent)

# importing
from Reporting import utils
```

... but this solution is kind of a non-starter since VSCode tells me "`Import "path" could not be resolved by Pylance`". I tried to fix this by running `py -m pip install path`, but that still didn't fix anything because I got `Exception has occurred: AttributeError: module 'path' has no attribute 'path'`. Then I changed `path` to `Path` which VSCode seemed to like better, but after all that I got right back to where I started with the `No Module named 'Reporting'` error.

What's going on here? What's the best way to import this? I feel like I'm making this a lot harder than I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your directory tree, `utils` is not located inside `Reporting`.

First solution fixed:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:\\marketing-reports')
import utils
```

Optional solution, depending on your way of running the code:

```
from ..... import utils
```

I do believe you might need to repackage `utils.py` somewhere else, but for simple uses these solutions will work.

Comment: Hey bharel! Thanks for this. Looks like I missed something really simple. Your suggestion worked.

Where would you put the `utils` file? It is going to be used by dozens of different projects inside one of the folders in `Reporting/`, and there may be between 1 and 5 directories from `utils` and the file using it.

Comment: @PatrickCallahan You're welcome. If this answer solved your question, you're welcome to mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: I will as soon as StackOverflow lets me. Looks like I got to wait a few minutes. In the meantime, I made an edit to my above comment with a question. Any idea on that one? Thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickCallahan to be honest, I'm not entirely sure where to put it. At first I thought maybe in a completely different directory tree, but as these look like a collection of scripts, it might be the best location. I'm not happy with it, but I'm not sure if there's a better way that will keep it simple as it is.

Comment: Do you know how to establish a parent directory? I wanted to change from my `sys.path` solution because, with that solution, Pylance cannot access the Reporting.utils file, which makes it a lot less convenient to use. It looks like Pylance can access this file when I use the `....` solution, but with that solution I get an error like `attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I already have an `__init__.py` file in the same folder containing the `utils.py` file. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Treat `marketing-reports` as a package. First change its name to `marketing_reports`. Next  run the code like so: `cd C:\ && py -m marketing_reports.Reporting.Adhoc.for_sales.salesperson1.current`. For more info about running modules see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

Comment: Words cannot express how thankful I am. I really struggle with packages and imports and it seems really obtuse to me. You put me on the correct path! Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickCallahan anytime. In this special scenario I would probably open the folder `C:\marketing_reports` in visual studio code, (file -> add folder to workspace) and then use `from marketing_reports import utils` in the code while running it the same way with the `py -m`. Pylance should recognize it and it will look a tad better than multiple `.....`